# How to use dagger2 subcomponent?

Tags: android, dagger

According to official documents：https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents.html ，I add a subcomponent in @Module, like this:

```
@Module(subcomponents = {MainActivityComponent.class})
public class ContextModule {

    private Context mContext;

    public ContextModule(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Provides
    public Context provideContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

}
```

And declare my component and subcomponent like this:

```
@Component(modules = ContextModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {
    Context provideContext();

    MainActivityComponent getMainActivityComponent();
}

@Subcomponent(modules = {HardwareModule.class, SoftwareModule.class})
public interface MainActivityComponent {
    void injectMainActivity(MainActivity activity);
}
```

But the code can not be compiled successfully. The error is this:

```
Error:(11, 1) : com.kilnn.dagger2.example.MainActivityComponent doesn't have a @Subcomponent.Builder, which is required when used with @Module.subcomponents
```

I don't know how to write a @Subcomponent.Builder , and if i remove the subcomponent declare in @Module, everything is ok. So i don't know what is the right way to use subcomponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the error is quite descriptive, all you need to do is add the Builder to your `Subcomponent` like this:

**MainActivityComponent.class**

```
@Subcomponent.Builder
interface Builder {
     MainActivityComponent build();
}
```

For your current implementation, and since you don't have special dependencies you don't really need the `Subcomponent`.

*Note: For convention's sake I recommend you to rename your **Subcomponent** to `MainActivitySubcomponent`*

Comment: Although it has been a long time, I also know how to use, but still have to thank your answer. Rename to `MainActivitySubcomponent` is a goog idea.

Comment: Well, I couldn't possibly know :). I just tried to help.

Comment: Srry to dig in old question, but @Joaquim Ley why you write, that > For your current implementation, and since you don't have special dependencies you don't really need the Subcomponent. I see that MainActivityComponent that is renamed as MainActivitySubcomponent and has two modules that AppComponent havn't.